# Архивация логов после n-ого

Tags: bat

Существует папка с логами. Логи дробятся с течением времени по 100мб. Необходимо старые по дате (*это все логи после 500-ого, если они существуют*) логи по отдельности запаковать в zip (или rar) и переместить в отдельную папку.

С логами от 1-го до 500-го никаких действий не производить.

**Задача:** Нужно написать бат файл который будет добавлен в Планировщик заданий Windows. Bat будет выполнятся ежечасно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе архиватора **7-Zip**. Задача добавлена в планировщик заданий Windows.

```
for /f "skip=500 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d c:\logs\*.log') do d:\arcivator\7za.exe a -sdel "d:\backup\%%~nF.7z" "c:\logs\%%F"
```

Происходит архивация *.log фалов после 500-го (по дате). Запакованные файлы перемещаются в отдельную папку.